# Creating a GUI application that wraps command-line programs on Linux and Windows

Tags: user-interface, process

I'm writing a GUI application that will let users interact with command-line programs.  The programs are crystallography programs, in this case.  They take a long time to run.

There's a certain common workflow using the command-line programs.  The output from one program is typically processed and then is used by other programs.  The user needs to be able to fill in various text boxes and select options that are sent to the command-line programs.

As I'm lazy and don't want to do more work than I need to, what tools are out there that will help me in doing this?  The software needs to work initially on Linux, but also running on Windows at some point would be neat.

Would also be neat if there was some sort of DSL for non-programmers to be able to extend/modify the GUI application (to add new programs and change the options and so on).

Comment: May be of interest: https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey
See also `zenity` CLI program 
And Gumbie: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~brinkman/software/gumbie/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [GTK Server](http://www.gtk-server.org/) it is easily scriptable from any language and since it runs as a service (bit like a browser) it can be used across systems.  That is, the system running the command line stuff can be on a powerful system and the GTK Server running on the user's desktop PC.  The examples are easy to follow and the matrix of versions and languages is bound to include yours.  If you are unlucky, just pick the closest combination for examples.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest having a look at the [Galaxy](https://web.archive.org/web/20101124073835/http://bitbucket.org/galaxy/galaxy-central/wiki/Home) web portal. It is basically a web based GUI to command line bioinformatics tools (but works equally well for any command line application), with workflow capabilities built in, and thus should have exactly what you're looking for.

It should be fairly easy to add your own wrapper, by following Galaxy's tool configuration format. See [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20090831233232/http://bitbucket.org/galaxy/galaxy-central/wiki/AddToolTutorial) for how to do this.

**Edit 2024 Note:**
Current web site [Galaxy Community Hub](https://galaxyproject.org/) maybe not contain response reference

Answer (score 0):

TCL/TK was the traditional way.
Today I would use python with either wxPython (more complete) or FLTK(simpler).

If you don't need to readback results from the commandline program it's much easier -
eg os.system("command options")

Answer (score -2):

You can use WShell and redirect stdin stdout.

```
object console = WShell.Exec(cmdLine);
if (console.StdOut.AtEndOfStream)
    s = Pipe.StdOut.ReadLine();
```

Downside that you still have to figure out how to hode console window. But it is easy one. You need to find this window by window title and set its properties to ivisible. Or use freeware some utility from internet which can do it automatically for you.