# Tool to generate GUI for command line program

Tags: windows, user-interface, command-line

I'm looking for a program that semi-automatically builds a GUI for a Windows command line program.

That is, I want to give it an arbitrary command line program and somehow describe its usage ("It takes a list of filenames, and the --foo and --bar options followed by a string") and it will create a new GUI wrapper program that allows selection of files with a "Browse" dialog box and has text boxes for foo and bar.

I remember having tried a program like this before, but I don't remember what is was called and google fails to remind me.

Comment: Related: [Creating a GUI application that wraps command-line programs on Linux and Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335855/creating-a-gui-application-that-wraps-command-line-programs-on-linux-and-windows)

Comment: This seems to do it https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about [Gumbie](http://www.ddj.com/184405022)?

[Gumbie highlights](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~brinkman/software/gumbie/):

- In theory at least, Gumbie allows you to build a GUI without ever using a GUI. It's the GUI hater's GUI builder...
- Gumbie provides reasonable defaults for the handling of a number of events, such as windowClosing.
- Gumbie comes with **some features (e.g., layers) that facilitate the creation of GUIs for text-stream based command line software**.
- The main module of Gumbie offers support for building java applications that can also be run as java applets within netscape or MS IE.

Here's [an example](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~brinkman/software/gumbie/).

Comment: That seems to be a general-purpose GUI toolkit. I am looking for something that automatically generates a wrapper GUI program for a command line program.

Comment: Do you have any examples of using Gumbie for this purpose? I can't find anything more than that single sentence that suggests it has any special support for wrapping command line programs.

Comment: This one, not sure whether it helps: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~brinkman/software/gumbie/

Comment: See also `zenity` unix command line tool https://www.howtogeek.com/107537/how-to-make-simple-graphical-shell-scripts-with-zenity-on-linux/